# Why does grep show me different output depending on my input file size?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I'm a little puzzled by the output of my `grep` command, it seems to be truncating results based on the size of `-f FILE`. For instance, consider a 1000-line file of strings, `patterns.txt`, e.g.:

```
adkgjwofjdjglkadjglkjasdfahdg
dsklfjsldkfjaghwioeghsdlkjfld
sdkljfsdkljghsdlfhkwhfklshdfo
...
sdklfjsdklfjsdklfjslkjghdfkjj
```

and a 1Gb `queryfile.txt` to search for my patterns. When I run

```
grep -F -o -f patterns.txt queryfile.txt | grep -c adkgjwofjdjglkadjglkjasdfahdg
```

In this case, the command reports 0 matches for the 1st line, (`adkgjwofjdjglkadjglkjasdfahdg`) of `patterns.txt`, even though there are 35 occurrences in `queryfile.txt`. I verified this by reducing the `patterns.txt` file to its first 10 lines. Rerunning

```
grep -F -o -f patterns_reduced-list.txt queryfile.txt | grep -c adkgjwofjdjglkadjglkjasdfahdg
```

Properly reports the 35 occurrences of `adkgjwofjdjglkadjglkjasdfahdg`.

What's happening?

Comment: Works for me (GNU grep 2.16).

Comment: Which platform are you running on?  Which version of `grep` are you using?  Can you reduce your data to an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
How do you create the `first_line_of_patterns.txt` text to pass to the `grep`?  I take it that it is some variant of `$(sed 1q patterns.txt)`, but you should show that step.

Comment: @dreamlax: for every possible variation of patterns? :)

Comment: How come that you use `-f patternfile.txt` in the first invocation of `grep` but omit the `-f` option in the second? As far as I understand `first_line_of_patterns.txt` contains a pattern, not text to search through.

Comment: @user1016274: He literally meant that. That's not a filename, that's the first pattern from `patterns.txt`.

Comment: GNU grep 2.16 is what I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't happen unless... your *patterns overlap*.

Check this example:

```
echo "xyxx" | grep -o -F yx$'\n'xy   # output: xy
```

This finds the second pattern (`xy`), and because of that it won't find the first pattern (`yx`).

```
echo "xyxx" | grep -o -F yx          # output: yx
```

Comment: I modified the original question to show what the patterns.txt file looks like. It could very well end up with two different lines in patterns.txt that could match to the same line in queryfile.txt. Would that be considered an overlap?

Comment: No. You don't match *lines*, you match part of the lines (unless those patterns match the whole line). With binary search shrink the pattern file until you find the pattern(s) that overlap(s) with the first pattern. When you remove all the overlapping patterns, you'll see 35 occurences again.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your answer better. Could you give me a hint or two about how I can 'shrink' (compress?) the pattern file to perform a binary search for overlapping patterns?

Comment: Remove patterns until there's no observed overlap (you get 35). The binary search approach is just a quick method to find something, as it cuts the state space in half. Throw out half the patterns, if no change, throw the other half out. Repeat this until you locate the problem.

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks so much for explaining it. Could I prevent this behaviour from grep without modifying the overlapping patterns?

Comment: Probably not.. Split the patterns into separate files so that no files have overlapping patterns.